# In Xcode, is there a way to list only relevant methods for an object?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is there some way in Xcode to enter an object's name, and then get a list of the methods that can be used with that object, sorted either hierarchically by inheritance or by return value type?

I know you can get a list of methods by pressing Control-Space after entering the object's name in standard bracket messaging syntax; however, this list often contains numerous methods that are not applicable to the given object. As a result, you still have to scroll through a bunch of garbage, and then look up the class definitions for the object, or reference custom object implementations you have created in order to see which methods will work.

Comment: `Relevant` is a very subjective word.  How do you define it?

Comment: By "Relevant" I mean methods that will work with a given object. For instance, I create a new object called "Person" that inherits from NSObject, and has one new method. However, when I initialize the "Person" object in my code and then send a message to that object, the list of methods includes "setNilValueForKey:(NSString *)" which appears to not apply, and which throws an exception if you try to use it. This method is also defined in "NSKeyValueCoding.h" which I have not included in my project (unless it's somehow part of NSObject?).

Comment: `setNilValueForKey:` is a part of the `NSKeyValueCoding Protocol` which is very fundamental to the way that you can access NSObjects. So the only way to avoid references like that is not to inherit from that base class. To quote Apple `The essential methods for key-value coding are declared in the NSKeyValueCoding Objective-C informal protocol and default implementations are provided by NSObject.`

Comment: I see...I guess if the list IS in fact all from inherited methods and variables, then my question revolves around if there is a way to organize this list to show methods from the most recently-defined objects first, such as my custom object class properties and methods before listing those from "NSObject" (I'm very new to this).

Comment: Apple keep promising, we keep waiting. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Zaph Wait to long and your still working iMac isn't allowed to run the latest Xcode .. grrr.. mumble .. hate apple ..

Comment: @tkessler I can't help you with that other than to say that the longer you work with it the more familiar you will be and after a while it won't all seem like noise

Comment: @PeterM Ok, will work through it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tkessler Believe me .. I know its all very confusing at the start and there is a bucket load of stuff you `need` to know all at once.  Just bear with it.